# Import EC Key into Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

The Azure web portal only allows importing RSA keys into Key Vault. You can *generate* an EC key but not import one. Is there a way to programmatically import an EC key?

EDIT

My solution:

```
$p8Raw = Get-Content -Path .\KEY.p8 | ? {$_ -ne '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' -and $_ -ne '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'}
$p8Bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($p8Raw -join '')

$cng = [System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsaCng]::Create()
$len = $null
$cng.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey($p8Bytes, [ref] $len)
$params = $cng.ExportParameters($true)

$ToBase64Url = { Param($Content) [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Content).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').Replace('=', '') }

$pubX = & $ToBase64Url -Content $params.Q.X
$pubY = & $ToBase64Url -Content $params.Q.Y
$prvD = & $ToBase64Url -Content $params.D
$jwk = @{ crv = 'P-256'; d = $prvD; kty = 'EC'; x = $pubX; y = $pubY }
$RequestPayload = @{ key = $jwk } | ConvertTo-Json

$token = Get-MsalToken -Scope 'https://vault.azure.net/user_impersonation' -ClientId $ClientId -TenantId $TenantId -Interactive

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "${VaultUri}keys/${KeyName}?api-version=7.3" -Authentication Bearer -Token ($token.AccessToken | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) -Method Put -Body $RequestPayload -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This REST endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/import-key/import-key) should be able to do it based on this line:

> The import key operation may be used to import any key type into an Azure Key Vault.

I think the easiest would be to use any of the [official SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/developers-guide#apis-and-sdks-for-keys) (Java,.Net, Python, etc.) but if you are willing to put together the right HTTP request, that should work too.

Comment: Good find! I used MSAL.PS and PowerShell to invoke the REST API. Looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone with the supported Powershell cmdlets or Azure CLI.

- `Import-AzKeyvaultKey` from powershell.
- `az keyvault key import` from Azure CLI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/add-azkeyvaultkey?view=azps-8.0.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/key?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-key-import

Comment: The format of my key wouldn't have worked with the PowerShell Cmdlet. It's a PKCS#8.